# Invalid certificate received from server

Tags: android

WebAPI (built with .Net) is hosted on a server and called from iOS and Android apps using HTTPS.  No changes has been made in certificates or otherwise. iOS app works fine, web app using the same api works fine but since this morning all Android apps (running on Android version 5x or less only) using the API has stared crashing with this error.

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server.
```

Checked certificates, certificate chain, everything.   No issues.  If the certificate is invalid, no other apps should be working and why all of a sudden.  Can someone point to where to look.  I searched this site and found a few threads but their solutions require changes in Android app code. That can't be done (and deployed) so quickly.  Why all of a sudden, if someone can throw some light on it.  Even nothing has been updated in our test Android devices.

Tested the server through ssllab and handshakes come on Android simulations:

[image]

Comment: Check what TLS protocol is expected on the server and TLS protocols your app supports[.](https://android-app-promotion.com/) TLS generates error similar to wrong certificate.

Comment: Server supports TLS 1.2, 1.1, 1.0 and I guess Android versions less than 5 requires 1.1.  Until yesterday all devices were working fine. Now none of Android device (have only checked version 4.4 or less) is working.  Nobody has touched the server, nothing is updated or changed.

Comment: May be certificate is expired?

Comment: No, valid till 2019. If it was expired, iOS and WebApp using the same certificate would not have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved and the app on those older Android versions works now. I had to disable COMODO root certificate `COMODO RSA Certification Authority with SHA1 key afe5d244a8d1194230ff479fe2f897bbcd7a8cb4` in certificate manager everywhere it was. Apparently windows update added this and it was somehow conflicting and making an intermediate certificate not being sent from the server (in the second certificate chain, the first chain was ok).  Normally if an intermediate certificate is not sent, clients download it from the issuer but Android mono framework apparently doesn't do that.

Thank you Adm Selec https://community.qualys.com/thread/15295 for the solution.